# Understanding NodeJS Client and Server Security

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, server, client

When developing node.js Apps

```
You can run client on localHost:3000

and the server on localHost:5000
```

I have succesfully migrated my server to an aws EC2 instance and I have access to it by checking the DNS/URL

[www.myserverURL.com](http://www.myserverURL.com)

I've set it up to run on default port 80 with sudo rights

Now My Question,

What is preventing anybody from copying my client code, and sending my server false work.

This is how my client points to the server for a socket.io example.

Do I need to add security on the server side, semi-cors `if (not from this location)return null`

```
const ENDPOINT = "www.myserverURL.com";

const Chat = ({ location }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(room);
    console.log(location.search);
    setName(name);
    setRoom(room);
    console.log(socket);
    socket.emit("join", { name, room }, () => {});
    return () => {
      socket.emit("disconnect");
      socket.off();
    };
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);
```

Comment: Nothing will prevent copying client code and sending false work, unless you add it.

Comment: If you need to restrict some of the incoming data, then yes you need to add security on the server side. CORs won't protect you from a bad actor. 
Restriction normally requires some sort of authentication, then operations can only be completed via some server side data for that user.

Comment: If you can describe the `useEffect` process in more detail and the data you want to protect people might be able to give a more concrete example.